# Process found by netstat is not listed in ps command and unable to be killed

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, process, netstat

I am running MINGW64 command line on Windows 7.
I want to find the process which occupies port 8082 by using 'netstat' and kill it. But an error occurs saying "No such process".

```
$ netstat -aon | grep 0.0.0.0:8082
TCP    0.0.0.0:8082           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3960

$ kill -9 3960
bash: kill: (3960) - No such process
```

Then I run 'ps' command but can not find any process with pid 3960

```
$ ps -a
  PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
 2716       1    2716        884  pty0      197108 09:53:42 /g/Apps/Java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java
 4696    5248    4696       2740  pty2      197108 11:05:22 /usr/bin/bash
 5248       1    5248       5248  ?         197108 11:05:22 /usr/bin/mintty
 5256    4696    5256       4032  pty2      197108 11:16:33 /usr/bin/ps
```

Then try 'taskkill' command, but it is still not working and shows wired characters...

```
$ TASKKILL /PID /F 3960
▒▒▒▒: ▒▒Ч▒▒▒▒/ѡ▒▒ - 'C:/Program Files/Git/PID'▒▒
▒▒▒▒ "TASKKILL /?" ▒▒▒˽▒▒÷▒▒▒
```

I am confused and don't know how to kill such a non-existing process.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've created a post at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange for this issue.

Comment: Here the link to the post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381656/process-found-by-netstat-is-not-listed-in-ps-command-and-unable-to-be-killed - I wonder if Unix&Linux is the right place for mingw questions. How about superuser? Btw, the process could be a pure windows process and thus not visible in the `ps -a` process list (but I'm a Linux guy, I might be wrong)